# How exactly does elasticsearch versioning work?

Tags: elasticsearch

My understanding was that Elasticsearch would store the lastest copy of the document and just update the version field number? But I was playing around with a few thousand documents and had the need to index them repeatedly without changing any data in the document. My thinking was that the index size would remain the same, but that wasn't the case ... the index size seemed to increase.

This confused me a little bit, so i just wanted to seek clarification on the internal mechanism of versioning within elasticsearch.

Comment: unless I am wrong, it keeps only the latest copy of the document and updates the version field number, except during delete operations, where it remembers the details such as index, version number,etc for a 60 second interval. The index size increase might be caused by some other factor. Keep us posted on your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update is a Delete + Insert Lucene operation behind the scene.
But you should know that Lucene does not really delete the document but mark it as deleted.

To remove deleted docs, you have to optimize your Lucene segments.

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_optimize?only_expunge_deletes=true'
```

See [Optimize API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-optimize/). Also have a look at [merge options](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/merge/). Merging segments happens behind the scene at some time.

For a general overview of versioning support in Elasticsearch, please refer to the [*Elasticsearch Versioning Support*](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support/).

Comment: Thank, you I think this answers my initial question. Here's my follow up. Doesn't the refresh interval take care of this? ie won't ElasticSearch merge the changes together into segments after so many seconds ... so I don't have to run optimize?

Comment: No. Refresh will commit Lucene segments. But Lucene segments are immutable. So the only way to remove something in segments is to rewrite new segments without the deleted documents.
Let me add that optimize is an heavy task and can run for hours! So use it with caution.

Comment: Also, if you need to update a full index, it could be a best option to reindex everything in a new clean index, and then remove the old index. Using aliases will help a lot to avoid downtime for your users as you can switch your queries from an index to another one on the fly.

Comment: wow ... sounds like update isn't as sweet as I thought it was, does it do this delete+insert on partial updates as well?

Comment: I forgot to say that Lucene is also merging segments at some time and automatically remove deleted docs. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/merge/

Comment: So looking through the documentation in Elasticsearch, it doesn't seem as if an update does a delete+insert any longer at least according to this documentation ... http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/update/ ... partial updates also seem to be pretty lightweight ... with changes being merged into the document vs a full reindex ... **The update API also support passing a partial document (since 0.20), which will be merged into the existing document (simple recursive merge, inner merging of objects, replacing core “keys/values” and arrays)**

Comment: It a question of point of view. I was talking on a Lucene level. Partial updates are not lightweight. The gain you get with _update API (which is different than _insert again with the same _id) is the network bandwith and less risk to have a conflict (_version). Make sense?

Comment: I see. So even though its a partial update it still goes through the same segment insert+delete process ... on a lucene level, correct?